# Error: haven't defined the object

Tags: vba, excel

I am just referencing some sample code ,that want to move An Excel table Into A new word document.

However , it contains at least one error .

```
Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet9.Name).ListObjects("Table1").Range
```

> Error: Need object here.

Link :
https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/5/22/copy-paste-an-excel-table-into-microsoft-word-with-vba

Full codes:

```
Sub ExcelRangeToWord()

    'PURPOSE: Copy/Paste An Excel Table Into a New Word Document
    'NOTE: Must have Word Object Library Active in Order to Run _
      (VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library)
    'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

    Dim tbl As Excel.Range
    Dim WordApp As Word.Application
    Dim myDoc As Word.Document
    Dim WordTable As Word.Table

    'Optimize Code
      Application.ScreenUpdating = False
      Application.EnableEvents = False

    'Copy Range from Excel
      Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1.Name).ListObjects("Table1").Range

    'Create an Instance of MS Word
      On Error Resume Next

        'Is MS Word already opened?
          Set WordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")

        'Clear the error between errors
          Err.Clear

        'If MS Word is not already open then open MS Word
          If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")

        'Handle if the Word Application is not found
          If Err.Number = 429 Then
            MsgBox "Microsoft Word could not be found, aborting."
            GoTo EndRoutine
          End If

      On Error GoTo 0

    'Make MS Word Visible and Active
      WordApp.Visible = True
      WordApp.Activate

    'Create a New Document
      Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add

    'Copy Excel Table Range
      tbl.Copy

    'Paste Table into MS Word
      myDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteExcelTable _
        LinkedToExcel:=False, _
        WordFormatting:=False, _
        RTF:=False

    'Autofit Table so it fits inside Word Document
      Set WordTable = myDoc.Tables(1)
      WordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)

    EndRoutine:
    'Optimize Code
      Application.ScreenUpdating = True
      Application.EnableEvents = True

    'Clear The Clipboard
      Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End Sub
```

Comment: My best guess is that you are confusing a worksheet's *name* with a worksheet's *codename*. In the above, you are using a codename to retrieve the name. What worksheet (name) is Table1 on and what is the codename from the VBE's VBA Project window (Ctrl+R) that is associated with that worksheet name?

Comment: And if your macro workbook **does** have a sheet with a `CodeName` of `Sheet1` (or `Sheet9` according to the error?!?) containing a table called `"Table1"`, then `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1.Name).` can be shortened to just `Sheet1.`

Comment: @YowE3K ` What do you mean containing a table call `table1` ?`

Comment: You are attempting to use `....ListObjects("Table1")` which (AFAIK) refers to the table called "Table1", i.e. what the default table would be called if you inserted a table on your worksheet.  Do you have a table on your worksheet?  If not, that is probably why you can't access it.

Comment: @YowE3K  ` refers to the table called "Table1", ` which means the worksheet called "table1" ? I have ! Now prompt out `array list out of bound`

Comment: `ListObjects("Table1")` means a **table** called `"Table1"`, not a worksheet called `"Table1"` (although I guess it is possible that your `Sheet1` worksheet is called `"Table1"` and also contains a table called `"Table1"`).

Comment: @YowE3K Omg .I don't know it is possible to insert a table into excel . I just want to select a range (like A1:E10) and paste into word document .how to modify the codes?

Comment: I would **guess** that it would be as simple as saying something like `Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("whatever_sheet_name_you_are_using").Range("A1:E10")`.

Comment: @YowE3K You may deliver the answer . I will mark it as correct .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the information you supplied in comments, it appears you don't actually have a table in your worksheet (which is why `ListObjects("Table1")` wasn't returning an object) and you actually just want to transfer a `Range`.

If so, replace the line setting `tbl` with something like:

```
Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("whatever_sheet_name_you_are_using")‌​.Range("A1:E10")
```